# Cloud Firestore: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting (on Android):

> com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException:
>   PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions

using these security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

My app seems to be properly authenticated using `FirebaseAuth`, as the `mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()` returns the proper user ID.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's happening to me too. Until yesterday everything worked find, but since today it keeps returning permission error. I checked my security rules, and nothing is wrong. The weird behavior is it works sometimes, and it doesn't work sometimes with exactly same code. Did u fix the problem?

Comment: This is happening occasionally on web and react-native(firebase-ios-sdk) as well. The problem should be in firestore and not on the client sdk.

Comment: Still having the same problem, have you managed to resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** just want to say that I managed to fix the issue by downgrading to 4.6.2. I have more details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48073760/2872979)

**Pre-edit:**
This is happening to me ever since I upgraded react native and I cannot for the life of me figure out the problem. I've debugged it and my user is definitely authenticated at the time of the request, I checked this by running the below and I have a uid in there

```
firebase.auth().currentUser
```

So the next thing I wanted to do was check the session in the actual request to see what was happening. I added a piece of code to the entry point of my react app

```
XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest ?
GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest :
GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest
```

and when I run this code it magically works again. This is delegating requests through the browser though so probably not a true test.

So then I started up Charles and compared the requests for my new react-native build with my old [working] react-native build. The requests look the same to me though (apart from a different sessionId) so I have no idea. The frustrating thing is the lack of debug tools through the firestore console.

My gut is to say some of the auth headers are expired/cached and that it's not firestore. Banging my head against a table at this point

Comment: Using `firebase@4.6.2` worked for me as well. Thank you, never would have figured this out

Comment: Hi there, I was wondering if you'd be able to shed light on this matter. Looks like I've got it too in both react js and native. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929366/cloud-firestore-reactjs-error-missing-or-insufficient-permissions

Answer (score 1):

It seem it's a `Firestore` problem (in beta today), not in the client side.

Comment: Still having this issue (occasional Missing or insufficient permissions), with Android SDK updated.

Do you think this issue has still not been resolved by Firestore ?

Comment: I am using Firestore in a small Angular 6 project and I still have the same problem as I write.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the Firebase support team directly since this issue was kind of critical for our service and I received the email below. It seems they fixed the bug now.

Please let me know if the issue happens again.

> Hi there,
>
> We have just confirmed with our engineers that this sporadic issue
>   with our Security Rules for Firestore was a known bug but was already
>   fixed today. Kindly test your security rules again and let us know if
>   you are still encountering the issue.
>
> Regards, Kevin

Comment: I'm having this problem now. I was able to submit data this morning - now I'm not. I didn't change anything and am getting this permissions error. I'm well within my usage limits